# F# function composition changes base function types

Tags: types, f#, f#-interactive

I'm working through [this F# wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Higher_Order_Functions) and I'm confused at something I'm seeing in the function composition section of the linked page.

The simplest example I can come up with follows:

```
// int -> int
let f x = x + x
// float -> float
let g x = x + 1.0
```

This is fine. I understand the types of these functions easily and I can run them in fsi and confirm that they take and return values of the types I've called out above.

If I add the following line, then I see the change I'm not so sure I understand.

```
// equivalent to f (g x)
let fog = f << g
```

The way I understand this, it shouldn't work because f expects an int, but g returns a float.

If I define this composition in fsi, I get the expected type error. If I put all these in a .fsx file and send the whole thing to fsi, the signature of f becomes float -> float.

I am confused as to the following:

- scope of the type inference happening?
- what is different between defining these in a file and in fsi?

I have tried searching, but I don't know enough at this point to effectively find answers to these questions. I'll be happy to RTFM if you can help point me to the parts that address these.

Comment: Your assumption is correct. It will always fail. I can't reproduce the scenario you mentioned to make it work, by saving it in a file and I can't believe that by just doing that it will infer ``float->float``. You might be testing the wrong way. Please check again.

Comment: Apologies, I mistyped my example and have updated it. There shouldn't be a 1 in the definition of f. Without the composition step, f is int -> int when defined as follows. With the composition function it is float -> float.  

let f x = x + x

Comment: OK, now I can answer your question ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The confusion comes from the fact that while the `(+)` operator is generic, it has a default type which is `int` so depending on the rest of the code you are compiling it will apply or not the default type.

This means that if you give type inference only this:

```
let f x = x + x
```

It will be inferred as `int` but it could have been any other numeric type that support the `(+)` operator, but since you gave no more information it uses the default.

Note that F# has to choose a type for this function in order to be encoded in .NET type systems, unless you define it `inline`, if you do so it will remain generic.

```
let inline f x = x + x

// val inline f :  x: ^a ->  ^b when  ^a : (static member ( + ) :  ^a *  ^a ->  ^b)
```

Now if you compile additional code along with that line, that uses the function `f`, type inference can analyze the types and get a more accurate candidate.

Here's a simpler example, open a new script and paste this code:

```
let f x = x + x
let v = f 1.
```

Now execute it line-by-line by pressing `CTRL` + `'` at each line, it will infer `int` and will fail on the second line.

But now select the whole script and press `ALT` + `ENTER`, it will compile and `f` will be inferred with `float` since it was able to use the information of the following line which uses `f`.

Comment: Thanks. Can you point me toward any further reading I could do on how this type inference happens?

Comment: This blog mentions the same example you posted: http://withouttheloop.com/articles/2014-10-21-fsharp-adhoc-polymorphism/

Comment: Also check the section 1.1.3 of the [F# 4.0 spec](http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/4.0/FSharpSpec-4.0-latest.pdf)

Comment: Thanks very much for you help!